# If the product of two sequences of positive numbers converges to a positive number and one of them converges, does the other one as well?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(a_n)_n, (b_n)_n \subset \mathbb R^{>0}$ be sequences of positive numbers. We know that $\lim_n a_n = a \in \mathbb R^{>0}$ and $\lim_n (a_nb_n) = c \in \mathbb R^{>0}$. Can we deduce from this that a subsequence of $b_n$ converges? In other words, is there an example of such sequences such that $b_n \rightarrow \infty$? I suspect not, but I haven't able to show that $b_n$ must have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: 1/ What can you say about $\lim 1/a_n$?  2/ What can you say about $ \lim (1/a_n) \times a_n b_n$?

Comment: No it’s not true, let one of the sequences be $0$…

Comment: @CalvinLin You must make a bounded away from zero assumption.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku  How could a question not be true? $\quad$ That's part of what can be said in response to the 2 questions.  $\quad$ Note that the title differs slightly from the text, which is another reason I didn't want to be explicit with the assumptions/conditions.

Comment: @CalvinLin I didn't have space to put all assumptions in the title, sorry about that.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku I want to assume that all sequences consist of strictly positive numbers, so I can't take one to be $0$.

Comment: It doesn’t not matter take a sequence converging to 0, and a bounded sequence…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $\lim a_n = a > 0$ makes this true.  We know that, for all $n$ sufficiently large, we must have $a_n > \frac a2$ by the definition of convergence.  For such $n$, we have $a_n b_n > \frac a2 b_n$, and since $a_n b_n$ converges, we must have that $b_n$ is bounded and hence has a convergent subsequence.

As the comments have pointed out, if $\lim a_n = 0$ this need not be true.  As an example, let $a_n = \frac 1n$ and $b_n = n$.